# error messages in algorithm package

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic

I got these errors while writing an algorithm. Can anyone help?

> Missing number, treated as zero.
>
> \ALG@currentblock@0  l.273 \end{algorithmic}
>
> Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
>
> l.273 \end{algorithmic}
> I was expecting to see `<',` =', or `>'. Didn't.

The algorithm structure look like this:

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
 \caption{my Algorithm}
 \begin{algorithmic}[1]
 
\FOR {$iteration=1,2,\ldots$}
\STATE  cdss
\ENDFOR
\ENDFOR $t_i$
\RETURN $M^{(R)}$ and $\eta_{t}$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

this is my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm, algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
 \caption{,MY Algorithm}
 \begin{algorithmic}[1]
 \renewcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Input:}}
 \renewcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Output:}}
 \REQUIRE {aaa}
 \ENSURE  { bbb}
 \\ \textit{111} :
\FOR  {$iteration=1,2,\ldots$}
   \STATE  mmm 
     
     \FOR{$iteration=1,2,\ldots$} 
          \STATE   nnnnn
     \ENDFOR

     \FOR {$iteration=1,2,\ldots$}
          \STATE  hhhh
     \ENDFOR
     \FOR {$iteration=1,2,\ldots$}
          \STATE    bbb
     \ENDFOR

\ENDFOR 
\RETURN $t^{(m)}$ 
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Looks like you are mixing `algorithmic` and `algorithm2e`

Answer (score 1):

Yo are mixing two different packages for algorithms **and** you have two `\ENDFOR` statements in **one** loop (which throws an error). Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm, algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{my Algorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \For {$iteration=1,2,\ldots$}
          \State  cdss
        \EndFor $t_i$
        \Return $M^{(R)}$ and $\eta_{t}$
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i tried updated the code but error is still there.. updated the code in question please have a look

Comment: @Alex Sometimes, when an error arises, you have to delete auxiliary files such as the aux file.  For algorithms, there may be additional files, corrupted from a prior compilation.

Comment: i am working on overleaf is there any aux fule generated by overleaf? i cant see sorry for stupid question as i am new to latex

Comment: @Alex – Your updated code hangs at the very beginning. Where are all the keywords (e.g. `\REQUIRE` or `\FOR`) defined?

Comment: dont know i just copied from different links to make it work on my scenario

Comment: Please make your updated code compilable by adding the definitions of the keywords. Also: don't just copy "from different links", you will run into problems every time.